# Get Rid of Error Message

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, error-logging

I have a script with many commands. Like

```
#!/bin/sh
mv new /root/
mv old /root/ 
mv foo /code
#many other commands
```

If the file 'new' is not found bash will give an error message:`foo: No such file or directory`

I can suppress the error message by redirecting all output from stderr to /dev/null

```
mv foo /code 2>1 /dev/null
```

Questions:
Is there a way to simply do it without modifying whole script?
Is there a way in which to suppress all the error message in a script?

Comment: You can redirect all of stderr when running the script, i.e. `./myscript.sh 2 > /dev/null`

Comment: Question: Do you mean the normal bourne shell (as in your /bin/sh example) or bash (which you tagged it with).

Comment: yes normal shell

Comment: The question is why you're writing a script that you *expect* to throw errors on files that aren't found. You should check if the source file(s) and the target(s) exist(s) before moving it/them somewhere. The proper way to get rid of an error message is to prevent the error from happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress **all messages** in the script by starting the script like this:
[`yourcommand &>filename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script).  E.g. `./myscript &> /dev/null`

Or you could use `your_script 2> /dev/null`

The last will redirect all output from **stderr** to the bitbucket with no need to append that to every command. Since this removes all the errors from the visible output this will make the script very hard to debug. You should check the return value of each command to see if an error occurred and optionally abort.

You can do the latter with `$?`.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mv new /root/
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
   #ignore error since it is not important, or
   #
   # echo "YIPES! CRITICAL FAILURE. Aborting whole script!
   exit 1
fi
Next command here
```

Etc etc.